Upload file long name failed laravel livewire
enter image description herePlease help, I'm a newbie, And I have mini project for e-documents using laravel and livewire,
When I try to upload file that has long name then got error, also can't catch the error.
when the file has short name is work fine

On some Windows systems the maximum file path length is 256 characters. From Windows 10 V1607 and later the limit can be removed (see here ). However to get better help you need to provide a minimal reproducible example
